# arcgis map not displayed in android after some processing in various activities

Tags: android

Hi in my arcgis android application I add a new feature to a feature layer after processing data in various activities feature layer is updated but when I return to the main activity to display updated feature layer neither map nor feature layer is displayed In  the log cat I found

url =http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Reference/World_Boundaries_and_Places/MapServer
com.esri.core.io.EsriServiceException: **Request Time-out**
at com.esri.core.internal.io.handler.c.a(SourceFile:563)

Comment: please edit your question, it's completely unclear what you asking

Comment: actually its related to GIS domain like google map etc easy for experience to understand Actually a map like google map is displayed in my app I add a layer to it but when I want to display map at the end I am getting request time out

Comment: don't write it in comments, update question